# Programmatically switch to navigation view on TableViewCell click in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I was able to create an iOS application in which you could switch between views with buttons. These views had a navigation controller so you could go back.

However I want to adapt this slightly.

Instead I want to have a single view start with no navigation controller.
Then when a cell in my table view is clicked, I want to navigate to the next view which has a navigation controller.

I can make this happen using segue in the interface builder but I don't want to manage it through the builder. This is because I only want to go to the next view when I have done some checking on the cell clicked in the table view.

So basically I need to programmatically change views.

Here is what I have done so far:

- I have an ordinary View Controller.
- I then have next to it a Navigation Controller which is linked to a new View Controller after that.
- I gave this View a storyboard ID of presetController.

I then have the below code in my table cell onclick function:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presetController") as! PresetNavigationController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Now this code takes me to the next view, but no navigation controller is loaded.

How can I make the navigation controller link to this view? It already is embedded to it via the editor tab link.

Photo to explain story board:

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMXjk.png)

Comment: can you post screenshot of storyboard?

Comment: Storyboard image added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap View Controller with Navigation Controller and then do this code:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presetController") as! PresetNavigationController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

this will make your navigationbar back button appear

Comment: It's the view controller on the right, i don't know the name, because it's not visible on the printscreen neither on your code, but basically you need to have:

NavigationController -> ViewController (with tablecell) -> The SecondViewController

Comment: How do I swap them?

Comment: Is the ViewController your initial view controller?

Comment: If you see the photo I put in the code I have 2 view controllers. The first (left one) is my initial.

Comment: So just make NavigationController the initial one, then set viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller with a segue, and just use the code you have

Answer (score 0):

If your link Navigation controller from New controller and Your are opening presntview controller than you will be make as this

```
  let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presetController") as! PresetNavigationController

  let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)

  self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You are showing present view controller you can only dismiss this. If you want to back button than you should you push view controller and made to Navigation controller in appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions from ppinho I put the navigation controller as the entry point.

As I did not want the navigation controller on the first view I hid it with the below code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

I then added the new view to the navigation like so:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presetController") as! PresetViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
let nextScreen = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextScreenIdentifier") as! NextScreenControllerName
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextScreen, animated: true)
```

write this inside any function of the viewcontroller.